# How to stop creation of multiple indexes on same column of same table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing

In Oracle, if we try to create two indexes on same column of same table then it gives ORA-01408: such column list already indexed.

```
create index tmp_idx1 on student(roll_no);
create index tmp_idx2 on student(roll_no);
```

> ORA-01408: such column list already indexed.

But, same if we try to create in Postgres, it allows.
How can we stop this in postgres and make behavior like in Oracle?

Comment: Write better migration scripts that don't try to do that?

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name, but maybe you can find useful event triggers https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createeventtrigger.html?

Comment: This is not a very desirable behavior.  It may help you (from yourself) in the design phase, but it prevents REFRESH INDEX CONCURRENTLY from doing its job.